# Tab Control with bootstrap not showing values of other tabs in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am designing a tab control but is not working. when select other tabs it doesn't change the data. here's the code

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

        <li><a class="active" href="#Mercedes-Benz" data-toggle="tab">Mercedes Benz</a></li>
        <li><a href="#BMW" data-toggle="tab">BMW</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Lamborgini" data-toggle="tab">Lamborgini</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class=" tab-content">
        <div class=" tab-pane fade in active" id="Mercedes-Benz">
            Mercedes Benz pics
        </div>
        <div class=" tab-pane fade" id="BMW">
            BMW pics
        </div>
        <div class=" tab-pane fade" id="Lamborgini">
            Lambo pics
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here are the imported files for this.

```
  <link href="assets/bootstrap%203.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.cs"></script>
```

it just shows 'Mercedes Benz pics' even after selecting other tabs.

also, how can this be turned to vertical tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see no error there, but give a try at this, since you are using bootstrap it might help: [Link1](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-vertical-tab) 
or this.